# PHP - My dropdown array list doesn't appear to show any query results

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm new to PHP and I'm having an issue figuring out how to fix this snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php 
//Connection details --- Do not delete
require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/connect.php";
?>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    //This places all table in the array and used as a dropdown list for "Select Table" form
    $table_fetch = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'meta_auto_reports' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'");
    $tables = array();
    while ($row = $table_fetch->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $tables[] = $row['table_name'];
    }

    ?>
    <h1>Select Table to View</h1>
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
        <select name="table">
            <option>Select Table</option>
            <?php
            foreach ($tables as $table) {
                echo "<option value='$table'>" . $table . " </option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>&nbsp;<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="View">
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//if the submit button is clicked
        $var_table = $_POST["table"];
        $query = "select * FROM meta_auto_reports.".$var_table."";
        $data = $dbh->query($query);
        while ($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            print_r($row);
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The Drop down list comes from listing out all tables in a schema meta_auto_reports, and it list out the tables perfectly. But my Submit button doesn't give a query result (not sure if the placing of closing tags, the value of the list and/or the php code itself isn't right).

Comment: change the `input type=button` to `input type=submit`

Comment: Holy Macaroni!..It worked..thanks :D

Comment: here I thought "Spaghetti" was the only holy thing on my plate! *Mama mia!!*

Comment: Well, @jtejido, I added it as an answer, do try to accept it.

Comment: You should be careful accessing `information_schema` you can get the same result from `USE DATABASE_NAME; SHOW TABLES;` I am fairly sure you need root access or an unnecessary set of privilages to access `information_schema`

Comment: Thanks for the tip sir ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your input type from `button` to `submit` like below:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="View">
```

Comment: Thanks again Pal.. :)